# PYQ ImportError: No module named pyq

Tags: python, kdb, pyq

I am trying to install pyq on 64 bit Ubuntu. I have a 64 bit KDB+ license. 
I followed the steps given in [Pyq Installation](https://pyq.enlnt.com/install/install.html) for installing in a licensed Kdb+.

I created a virtual environment.

```
pip install virtualenv
mkdir python-virtual-environments && cd python-virtual-environments
pyvenv env
source env/bin/activate
```

Unzipped the kdb+ 64 bit file

```
mkdir -p ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/q && unzip path/to/m64.zip -d ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/q
```

copied the license and installed pyq

```
git clone https://github.com/enlnt/pyq.git
pip install <path to the source>
```

I have also done the same process by creating a virtual environment using Conda.

In both cases, when I run pyq in the Terminal, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyq
'2017.10.11T06:10:31.641 python
```

Please help.

Also when I try to install pyq using

```
pip install -i https://pyq.enlnt.com --no-binary pyq pyq`
```

I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyq in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, uninstall pyq by running

```
pip uninstall pyq
```

Make a copy of the list of paths that this command displays as being removed. You will need it to troubleshoot later.

Make sure you have python shared libraries installed. See [Installing PyQ on Ubuntu 16.04](https://pyq.enlnt.com/install/install.html#installing-pyq-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Run

```
pip install pyq
```

Recently published versions don't require the extra pip options.

If this does not give you a working pyq executable, look at the list of paths that you saved during uninstall find the full path to the parent directory of the pyq package.  Set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to that path.

BTW, the message that you reported,

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyq in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

suggests that you (or someone else) installed pyq directly into local python installation, not into a virtual environment.  Also the `/usr/local` prefix indicates that you have a custom python installation which may be the cause of your problem.